# How can I remove borders for imageView in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, imageview

I tried to add android:adjustViewBounds="true" to my image and it doesn't do anything. How can I go past the border? My image is an icon 512x512.

`<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/needle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />`
[image: Here is what I have now.]
[image: This is the icon.]
[image: This is the issue I'm facing.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `android:background="@drawable/needle"` for your image, use `android:src="@drawable/needle"`. `android:background="@drawable/needle"` is for setting a background **behind** the image you want to display on your imageview. Edit: OP wants to make the line extend from left to right of the view. Changing `layout_width="wrap_content"` to `layout_width="match_parent"` should do the trick.

Comment: when I used android:src="@drawable/needle" the image appears shorter. I attempted to do android:scaleType="fitXY" and is still the same as it was when I did android:background="@drawable/needle"

Comment: Can you upload the image you're trying to use? And the image is supposed to appear shorter. It should appear at whatever the real size of the image is, unless you use a scaleType

Comment: Alright I updated the images ^ I appreciate you helping me out

Comment: Your icon is only a horizontal line from the screenshot. Is that correct? What exactly are you trying to do with that line? Make it expand from left to right in the view, or fill up the entire view?

Comment: I want this line to reach the very left and very right of the screen

Comment: @davidgilman Try using match_parent for the width of the ImageView instead of wrap_content. Also, make sure that the parent of the ImageView also has a width of match_parent

Comment: Also, I think your image has a lot of space above and below the line. You should crop it so that it's only the part that you need. Otherwise, your layout might not look the way you want it to.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to delete the padding left and right of relative layout. Thank you for your help!